# How does Sphinx handle URLs

Tags: postgresql, sphinx

When working with PostgreSQL you can break apart a URL into several different lexemes when using full text search.  For example:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('http://www.example.com/dir/page.html');
                               to_tsvector                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 '/dir/page.html':3 'www.example.com':2 'www.example.com/dir/page.html':1
(1 row)
```

You can see that PostgreSQL has broken up `http://www.example.com/dir/page.html` into the url minus the protocol (`www.example.com/dir/page.html`), host (`www.example.com`) and the url_path (`/dir/page.html`).  This is handy because it will allow you to quickly search for `www.example.com`.

With that background, how does SphinxSearch handle indexing a URL?  Does it behave similarly to PostgreSQL in that it breaks apart a URL into parts so that it can be easily searched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it literally just breaks up the source text using any charactors not listed in charset_table

so normally . and / just count as seperators so a url will just be searchable by the groups of letters - usefully combined with phrase operator